# asking help for vhdl error

Tags: int, vhdl, ram

I am trying to write a code for RAM 16*4 on vhdl and the code is :

```
entity RAM_16_4 is
Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
       WR : in  STD_LOGIC;
       add : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
       Di : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
       Do : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));
end RAM_16_4;

architecture Behavioral of RAM_16_4 is

type RAM is array (15 downto 0) of std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
 signal int : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
 signal x : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
begin

process (clk,WR)
begin

if ( clk'event and clk='1') then
if ( WR='1') then
int<= conv_integer (add);
int<= Di;
end if;
x<=add;
end if;
end process;

x<= conv_integer (add);
Do<= x;

end Behavioral;
```

This is the error which is coming:
Type of int is incompatible with type of conv_integer.

how can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Because `conv_integer` (which comes from a non-standard library) returns something incompatible with your declaration of `int`. Funnily enough you hwve declared `int` and `add` to be the same type, so just assign without converting. Or delete that line altogether since the text line makes it useless.

Comment: Please indent your code, so we can read and understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`conv_integer` converts a `std_logic_vector` to an `integer`. You cannot assign that `integer` to a `std_logic_vector`. Why would you use `conv_integer` at all if you want to assign `add` to `int` or `x`? They are both the same type...

More important: please note that `conv_integer` is part of the **non-standardized** packages `std_logic_arith` or `std_logic_unsigned`, which you should not use. Instead you should use `to_integer(unsigned(...))` from the standardized package `numeric_std` here.

When implementing a RAM for an FPGA, you should reference the FPGA manufacturers handbook. For instance from the [Xilinx Synthesis User Guide](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2017_3/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf)

```
-- Single-Port RAM with Asynchronous Read (Distributed RAM)
-- File: rams_dist.vhd
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity rams_dist is
    port(
        clk : in std_logic;
        we : in std_logic;
        a : in std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
        di : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        do : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)
    );
end rams_dist;

architecture syn of rams_dist is
    type ram_type is array (63 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    signal RAM : ram_type;
begin
    process(clk)
    begin
        if (clk'event and clk = '1') then
            if (we = '1') then
                RAM(conv_integer(a)) <= di;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    do <= RAM(conv_integer(a));
end syn;
```

...Well, crap.... Xilinx is also using the wrong conversion function. Let's rewrite that to standardized code:

```
-- Single-Port RAM with Asynchronous Read (Distributed RAM)
-- File: rams_dist.vhd
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity rams_dist is
    port(
        clk : in std_logic;
        we : in std_logic;
        a : in std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
        di : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        do : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)
    );
end rams_dist;

architecture syn of rams_dist is
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;
    type ram_type is array (2**a'length-1 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(di'length-1 downto 0);
    signal RAM : ram_type := (others => (others => '0')); -- let's initialize it at zeros
begin
    ram_proc: process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if we = '1' then
                RAM(to_integer(unsigned(a))) <= di;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    do <= RAM(to_integer(unsigned(a)));
end syn;
```

Comment: Better ... actually use the type system instead of fighting it ... if your address is an unsigned number, communicate that fact in the design. Just declare `a` to  be `unsigned` (from numeric_std) or even `natural`. Cleaning up needless type conversions and making the code simpler is just a bonus. I'd go further and say too many type conversions is a sign there's something wrong with the design (like using std_logic_vector for something numeric)

Comment: @BrianDrummond True, but when you're developing building blocks (for instance for Vivado IP Integrator), you often need `std_logic` types on the (top level) ports...